# Angular: Automatically update a scope reference to an object defined in a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an angular app `myApp`with a service `myService`, holding an object `data`that is used by two Controllers, `parentCtrl` and `childCtrl` the latter inheriting from the former: https://jsfiddle.net/OleWahn/7ehLva10/2/

I reference `data` within `parentCtrl` by `$scope.data = myService.getData()` which also makes it accessible from `childCtrl`.

I define `data` in the closure of `myService`, hence `$scope.data` is just a reference to `data`.

Thus, I can alter `data`'s properties within the child controller and everyone, `myService`, `parentCrl` and `childCtrl` will be aware of these changes. So far, so good.

My problem here is the following: If I want to overwrite the entire `data` object I invoke `myService`s method `setData` within `childCtrl`.

Again, I'd like everyone to be notified that `data` has changed. 
`$scope.data` however still points to the initially defined object and will not be notified by `myService` that `data` has changed, which will stand as my final question:

**Is there a way to automatically update a scope reference to an object defined in a service?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different approaches to the problem:

#### $broadcast

Credit goes to @doctor_Nick42 for this solution:

I add a `$broadcast` to the `setData` method of `myService` and catch it in `parentCtrl` update `$scope.data` accordingly.

Check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ehLva10/7/ for the details.

#### Using a function

Found a possible solution - I can define `$scope.data` as a function
returning `myService.getData()`, that is

```
$scope.data = function() {
    return myService.getData();
};
```

The downside of this solution is that within the view I would need to refer to `$scope.data` as a function, i.e. `{{data()}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the destination argument of `angular.copy`

> ### angular.copy<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)</sup>
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> angular.copy(source, [destination]);
> ```
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

So instead of replacing the scope reference, retain the reference, empty it, and fill it with the new contents.

```
function setData(newData) {
    //DO this
    angular.copy(newData, data);
    //Instead of this
    //data = newData;   
}
```

Comment: This is even better than I thought it would be, thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't answer my original question though, I guess I did not really put it  very well. what if I *want* to change the references instead of exchanging the object's contents? Say for instance, I have an array containing several ``data``-like objects and I want ``$scope.data`` to point at  any of them. Now in ``childCtrl`` I'd like to alter that pointer via the setter of ``myService`` - how can I make ``$scope.data`` aware of that change?

Comment: @razzamatazz I'm not sure, if this is what you need, but maybe you should look at `$broadcast`. With this function you can 'notify' controllers about your data changes from the service. I know that overusing of `$broadcast` isn't a good practice, but maybe it could help you.

Comment: @doctor_Nick42 thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for! I'd edit my answer below to collect all solutions for the problem, but the credit for this goes to you